# Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, error, onepage-checkout, controllers

I keep getting the following error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setCollectShippingRates()
>   on    a non-object in
>   /chroot/home/Client/Client.com/html/app/code/local/Company/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
>   on line 12

I don't know if its something to do with $result or `setCollectShippingRates()` ? Maybe Varien Data somehow? Thanks for the help.

`app/code/local/Company/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

```
require_once'app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';

class Company_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    public function couponAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
        $this->couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');

        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getShippingAdress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode(strlen($this->couponCode) ? $this->couponCode : '')-> collectTotals()->save();

        $result['goto_Section'] = 'review';
        $result['update_section'] = array('name' => 'review', 'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml());

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}
```

Comment: One obvious problem is that you have misspelled `getShippingAddress`

Comment: Are you rewritting here a `OnepageController.php` ?

Comment: @Prince Yes. Making new module to add coupon form to review step of one page checkout.  Thanks Paj totally missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';

class Company_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController {
    public function couponAction() {
        $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
        $this->couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');

        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getShippingAdress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode(strlen($this->couponCode) ? $this->couponCode : '')-> collectTotals()->save();

        $result['goto_Section'] = 'review';
        $result['update_section'] = array('name' => 'review', 'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml());

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome  ;)

Comment: Thanks also @paj spelling error probably would not have helped either